# Postgres join IN array

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have a few rows with a column like this.

```
id,       bookName, authors

12323345, FatBook,  {1,3}
```

I am trying to join another table by values from the last column.
The type of the last column is text.

Joins won't work
like this

```
join users u on u."Id" IN books.authors
join users u on u."Id" IN books.authors::text[]
```

Expected results

```
12323345, FatBook, 1,3, John, Mark
```

or

```
12323345, FatBook, (1)John, (3)Mark
```

How do I do this? I will concatenate it later.

Comment: Please normalize the database design, at least to First Normal Form. Denormalized designs liek this one are good for direct, fast queries only, but not for joins.

Comment: @TheImpaler unfortunately I can't change the design of the database, my problem was with export some data to a file.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it might be useful for someone

My solution based on string_agg and subquery

```
SELECT
b."Id",
b."Name",
(
    SELECT 
        STRING_AGG(CONCAT(u."Id", '(',u."Name", ')') , ',')
    FROM "Users" u 
    WHERE u."Id" = ANY(b."Authors"::text[])
) AS 'Authors'
FROM "Books" b
```